# Dynamic Routing in Vue.js, not found

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apache

I have this index.js file for routing and arranged /game/:game for dynamic routing.

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import HomeView from "@/views/HomeView.vue";
import NotFound from "@/views/404.vue";

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "home",
      component: HomeView,
    },
    {
      meta: { title: "Game Detail" },
      path: "/game/:game",
      name: "gameDetail",
      component: () => import("@/views/GameDetailView.vue"),
    },
    {
      meta: { title: "404" },
      path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*",
      name: "NotFound",
      component: NotFound,
    },
  ],
});

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  const title = to.meta.title || null;
  const appTitle = "GameApp";
  document.title = title ? `${title} | ${appTitle}` : appTitle;
  next();
});

export default router;
```

Also I added this .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

But still, when I go domain.com/game/game_name, I got url not found error.

Comment: There's not enough debugging details to really know if it's vue router or something else.  Some immediate questions that come to mind: Does everything work in dev?  Do other routes work in production?  Did you build for production / what were your build steps?

Comment: @yoduh I'm running everything on production. the other routes works fine. I built for production. I run 'npm run build'

Comment: This is about client side routing, because some pages that work doesn't work when I refresh the page. But I add a .htaccess file so don't know what to do more